# DateTime.Now returns wrong value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

`DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.UtcNow`returns wrong value as you see in picture.
even `ToUniversalTime()` function result the same value.

How can I use DateTime with ignoring local time zone?

[image: DateTiem.Now returns local time]

Comment: This Can be Useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556149/date-and-time-zone-management-in-mvc

Comment: What do you mean by DateTime.UtcNow returns the wrong value? How can it be wrong? It takes time from where you are running your code, so your clock might be incorrect?

Comment: Why do you believe it's the wrong date? The debugger is rendering it in a culture that presumably doesn't use the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Please clarify your question in terms of what you *expect* the result to be. You almost *certainly* want to use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now` - that removes the time zone element, then you need to consider the inherent value of `DateTime` (which is always in the Gregorian calendar) vs the `ToString()` value the debugger is showing, which is culture-aware and will use your culture's default calendar system.

Comment: @MarkDavies, I expect full Gregorian Date with a DateTime UTC kind, but DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() returns local time

Comment: @Behzad When you say it returns local time, do you mean the actual hours/minutes are wrong?

Comment: No, `DateTime.UtcNow` returns the UTC Date and Time, `ToString` merely formats it to your local culture. You can specify which culture you want to use with one of the [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Additionally, it would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just a screenshot of the debugger. Show what you're trying to achieve - presumably you want these values as strings or something similar, so show that in code. It's very hard to help you without knowing what you're trying to achieve, in detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thak you, I expect ignoring local culture when I use ToString() method.

Comment: You still haven't edited your question to be clear though. The question would be much more useful with a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think my code produce the Persian Date only on my system OS, so how could I create a reproducible example?

Comment: Just showing what code you've got, what the output is on your system vs what you want it to be (and specifying the OS configuration) would be a lot better than just a debugger screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a culture (looks like one of the Arabic cultures) that doesn't use the Gregorian calendar. If that's not what you want, you need to use a different culture.

If you want an invariant culture, use the invariant culture:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This will produce the same string on every machine (provided the same `DateTime` value, of course) and can be parsed again with

```
DateTime.Parse("...", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you don't want the formatting for persistence, just pick whatever culture works for what you're trying to do. Each culture has its own calendar, number formatting etc.

Just to make this clear, `DateTime` values do not have formats. The format comes from the `ToString` (which is called implicitly in the debugger and many other places like `string.Format` or `<%= ...  %>`). `ToString` takes the current culture (per-thread) by default, so either change that (if it makes sense), or specify the desired culture explicitly when calling `ToString` (or `string.Format` etc.).

Comment: I would strongly advise against using `DateTime.Now` in any server-side work though.

Comment: @JonSkeet, so what should we use? ```DateTime.UtcNow``` ?

Comment: @BehzadShirani: Yes, almost certainly. It would be very unusual to want the time zone of the server to be relevant.